# How do I send a message to a specific channel in a server when the command was received in a DM?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to create an anonymous confession functionality for my Discord bot.

I want users to be able to DM the bot "!confess" and their confession and the bot will send a confession embed I've created to a specific channel in the server.

How do I call the channel in the server, when the command was not sent in a server?

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js' `Client` object has a property named `guilds` which is a map of all of the guilds that the Client is currently handling, mapped by their IDs (as long as sharding isn't being used, this will be every guild the bot is a member of).

You'll have to find the guild and then the channel within that guild which you want to send the message to.

```js
var guild = client.guilds.get("12345678910123456"); // get guild by id
var channel = guild.channels.get("12345678910123456"); // get channel within guild by id

channel.send("Your message");
```

Discord.js' channel objects are mapped by their IDs as well.

Comment: When I do this, I get an error in that second line that says "cannot read property 'channels' of undefined."

Comment: @Rayne Are you sure your guild ID is valid?